# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where I have 'element[i]' is me an error, but in console it is returning the element. This is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

```
function getElements(attrib) {
    return document.querySelectorAll('['+ attrib + ']') 
}

window.element = getElements('type=submit');

for (var i = 0; i <= element.length; i++) {
    element[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        showSpinner.bind(this, element[i])
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

Because indexed array starts from 0, you need to iterate to `array.length - 1`

So change `i <= element.length` to `i < element.length`

Error is caused by last element. If array has 5 elements, than last element index will be 4 instead of 5 and `<=` iterates including 5 leading to missing element `element[5]`

Answer (score -2):

Where you have

> ```
>  i<=element.length
> ```

You actually want

```
i<element.length
```

Comment: At least try to comment what is wrong...

Comment: @Justinas, everybody understands.

Comment: @Justinas, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324385/4928642

Comment: @dippas, meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324385/4928642